# Practical Question - How to Optimise Times over a Timeline

Tags: probability, calculus-of-variations

Let's assume you want to buy a blueberry muffin at your local bakery.

But, there are a few things that complicate the matter:

- The bakery is open from 6am - 1pm.
- Blueberry muffins are in high demand and they are only made one time per day. They sell out fast.
- You do not know the exact time that the muffins are made. However, you know at which times the bakery made them historically for the last 5 previous days. Let's say, those times are t1 = 6:45am, t2=8:00am, t3=8:45am, t4=7:10am and t5=11:30am.
- You have good reason to assume that there is some consistency in those times. But there might be outliers (such as t5).
- You really like blueberry muffins. But you think you should not walk to the bakery to check if the muffins are available more than 10 times per day.

A quick graphic to illustrate the issue:
[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47e9E.png)

Now my question is:
How can I mathematically optimise the time for my 10 visits to the bakery, based on the 5 historic data points? Goal is to optimise my overall chances to go home with some delicious muffins.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?  Also, if this problem is from a Math book or class (rather than a programming class), what Math training did you receive leading up to this problem?

Comment: Hi @user2661923 This is a real business problem, which I rephrased a bit to make it easier to understand. I received Math training at high school but that's many years ago haha

Comment: Interesting if only partial response.  Where did this *business problem* come from?  If the problem is from outside of any book or class, then okay, you have been caught in a situation where you have no training.  Alternatively, if the problem is from a book or class, then business class or not, the book/class should have provided you with tools that you could use to attack the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. It's from real-life, so it's not connected to any book or class.

Comment: See my comment, following the answer of antonoyaro8.

Answer (score 0):

Use the historical times to estimate a probability distribution function - then integrate this probability distribution function to interpolate regions with high probabilities corresponding to availability of muffins. Then visit the bakery around those times.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the process? OP only gave 5 items, but the probability is not really given.

Comment: Given the recent comment of the OP (i.e. original poster) it seems plausible that the OP's knowledge/experience with  *probability distribution functions* is almost as great as the OP's knowledge of life on the planet Neptune.

Comment: I guess, if this is real-life, I would just try to get more data and spread the intervals about 30 minutes apart. Then just try to make a histogram out of it. Finally, after enough samples, the answer should be more obvious. But I don't know what to do with 5 terms though.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would find out the time to expect before they are sold out. Then just match 2 visits to each data point. If you expect 30 minutes for a "window" of muffin sales, and 11:30 was a previous start time, divide it up evenly 3 ways (visit at 11:40 and 11:50). Do the same for the other 4 times. Or, if the times tend to be random, spread your visits out more, focusing on the most common data points (earlier in the day).